# Equal height DIVs with rounded corner border-image

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble forcing equal height DIVs when used in conjunction with a border-image to acheive rounded corners. The approach I've taken in the past was to make the divs very long and clip but that loses the border.

100% height works as long as the parent container has specific height (i.e. in px) but that loses the document flow if the content should grow. Any ideas how to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kky5crmx/2/

HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="rounded-corner-frame">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ligula erat, hendrerit at ullamcorper eget, ultricies sit amet magna. Quisque id leo sed neque finibus auctor. Sed nisi orci, feugiat in felis nec, iaculis ultrices risus. Nunc sodales rhoncus nunc, et venenatis arcu feugiat vel. Maecenas id ligula vel mauris rhoncus porta eu eget elit. Nulla vehicula lorem sapien, et tristique felis pharetra a. Mauris ultrices, turpis sed euismod varius, felis purus consequat enim, ac vehicula ex nunc sit amet libero. Mauris pellentesque tortor lorem. Fusce egestas aliquam urna eget bibendum.</div>

    <div class="rounded-corner-frame">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ligula erat, hendrerit at ullamcorper eget, ultricies sit amet magna.</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.rounded-corner-frame {
    border: 35px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: url('http://www.logitexsystems.co.uk/Temp/Rounded-Corner%20Frame.png') 35 35 fill;
    -webkit-border-image: url('http://www.logitexsystems.co.uk/Temp/Rounded-Corner%20Frame.png') 35 35 fill;
    -o-border-image: url('http://www.logitexsystems.co.uk/Temp/Rounded-Corner%20Frame.png') 35 35 fill;
    border-image: url('http://www.logitexsystems.co.uk/Temp/Rounded-Corner%20Frame.png') 35 35 fill;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting `display:table;` on `.container` and `display:table-cell` on the rounded corner divs

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/kky5crmx/4/)

The issue you will otherwise have is setting the equal heights...these will need to be set relative to a shared parent, which will in turn need to have a height set (as you note). By using the CSS table structure, you ensure both child 'cells' automatically stretch to the height of the one with the most content, without having to set tiered positioning / heights.